# Using Index function to capture the cells with value only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This might be a little hard to understand since I am not very good at explaining. I am also new to this community, so please let me know if I have something I should improve upon.

Essentially, I am trying to filter data horizontally. I have three Worksheets. Sheet1 has my data with "Company Name" listed horizontally, "Products" listed vertically, and "Yes/No" for the cells. I would like to transpose all the data from Sheet1 and put into Sheet2 where "Company Name" is vertical, "Products" is horizontal. Reason for doing so is that Excel only allow vertical filters. With data transposed, I can filter to see which company is able to make which products. BUT, I would still like my data to be in the format in Sheet one where "Company Name" is listed horizontally. Therefore, that is when my Sheet3 comes in and transpose all the data from Sheet2.
[image: This is the data I have in Sheet 1]
[image: This is the data I have in Sheet 2]
The way that I will get all the data from Sheet1 is by typing the following into Cell B2 as the formula:
`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$ZZ$291,COLUMNS($B2:B2), ROWS($A$2:$A2))`
I will drag this cell horizontally to until it displays all the "Products". Then, drag it down vertically to display all the "Companies".

However, when I want to add more "Companies" or add more "Products", I will have to drag the cells in Sheet 2 again to expand the data table to include the newly added ones.

My question is: When new data are inputted into Sheet1, is there a way to allow Index (in Sheet2 CellB2) to capture all the data on Sheet1 and update it onto sheet2 automatically?

Comment: If you have Office 365 you can use `TRANSPOSE()` you could combine it with `FILTER()` to have it update automatically.

Comment: 1st use table to retrieve even all the records, 2nd add a control in formula that count rows and columns in source, if `COLUMNS($B2:B2), ROWS($A$2:$A2)` are over return ""

Comment: Thanks for the reply, P.b. I tried this for on my empty Sheet3: `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!A1:BA1, Sheet1!A1:A100, ""))`. It showed me #VALUE!. I am not sure if this is compatible, I am using Excel 16.

Comment: Hi Terio, thank you for the reply. However, I am not too sure that exactly you meant. I am not sure what you mean by "retrieve _even_ all the records." And I am not sure about "add a control". Are you referring to something like `COUNTA()`?